# Starting Jetty via launch script does not work

Tags: java, jetty, init.d

I have a problem with starting Jetty via the startup command /etc/init.d/jetty. When I execute the command the following output is generated:

```
/etc/init.d/jetty start

Starting Jetty servlet engine.: 
Jetty Rotate logs
Jetty servlet engine started, reachable on http://jagadguru:80/.: jetty.
```

It does start successfully when I type `java -jar start.jar` in my Jetty directory.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you get an error? The typo in /etc/init.d/letty is not your problem i assume?

Comment: oh yeah it's jetty, sorry, no thats not my problem.

Comment: So, what is your error and what are the contents of /etc/init.d/jetty?

Comment: @MichaelStark, I get the same issue as you, did you eventually solve this problem?

Comment: A similar question is here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/running-jetty-webserver

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a file permission issue.  Even if you are running the start script with sudo, the script defines a jetty user (default is jetty).  I had an issue similar to this where my permissions on /tmp prevented jetty from creating a file there.  I adjusted the permissions on /tmp and all is well!  The jetty user also needs permissions on the jetty folder of course.

Also, for checking if Jetty is finding java correctly, run sudo service jetty check

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue due to wrong permissions on some work or log folder. I assume the start script tries to change the user and therefore doesn't has the same permissions as the one you use when running Jetty via "java -jar".

Another possibility is that you don't have JAVA_HOME set and the start script doesn't find your java bin.

Please attach some kind of log file as it is really hard to say more without more detailed information.

Comment: My question would be what to log, considering that if jetty fails to start then there will be no logs written.

Comment: I have the same issue. If $JAVA_HOME is not set, the script does not start and explicitly says that $JAVA_HOME is not set. As for the permission issue, I'm running it with 'sudo' doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @fabspro, the log would be in /var/log/jetty

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/running-jetty-webserver), the default configuration for Jetty in `/etc/default/jetty` only allows connections from `localhost`, you need to set `JETTY_HOST` to `0.0.0.0` to allow Jetty to accept connections from any host.

Add the following line to `/etc/default/jetty`:

```
JETTY_HOST 0.0.0.0
```